# Angular FlexBox custom media query

Tags: html, css, angular, flexbox, angular-flex-layout

By using angular flex layout custom queries I can show or hide some elements like this.

```
<span fxShow fxHide.lt-sm></span>
```

In the above example angular flex layout will show span except devices which is little than 599px in width.

My question is how can I use custom query in that context ?

Is that possible to do something like :

```
<span fxShow fxHide.('screen and (max-width: 677px)'></span>
```

Thanks.

Comment: There is much to explain, so you can simply follow the tutorial from docs: https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/Breakpoints